# How to return multiple values using API in django

Tags: json, django, api

I am brand new to django.

This is the api json value I called from internet:

```
{'message': '',
 'result': [{'name': 'ABC',   <------
             'Type': 'True',  <-----
             'Fee': 0.0005},
             {'name': 'DEF', <-------
             'Type': 'False',  <------
             'Fee': 0.004},
}
```

I want to put name and type to the webpage using HTML.

```
ABC True
DEF False
```

Do I need to modify models.py? Please give me an example. thank you
The only think I know is to use for loop in HTML, but I do not know does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In view.py

you can return data like

```
url = 'xxx'
response = requests.get(url)
# if your response is like : {'message': '', 'result': [{'name': 'ABC',  'Type': 'True', 'Fee': 0.0005}, {'name': 'DEF','Type': 'False', 'Fee': 0.004}] }
# then

list_result = response['result']

render(request, 'template.html', {"list_result": list_result})
```

Then you can send that `list_result` on HTML page and import `render` using

```
from django.shortcuts import render
```

To display data of response on HTML page use:

```
{% for data in list_result %}
  {{ data.name }} {{ data.Type }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It said 'Response' object is not subscriptable.     url = 'https://xxx'
    get = requests.get(url)
    response = get['result']

Comment: what is the result of `get` ?

Comment: thank you! It works! I did not put {"list_result": list_result} at the end of render!

Answer (score 2):

Just using forloop in template.

```
{% for r in result %}
{{ r.name }} {{ r.Type }}
{% endfor %}
```

#### Updated answer with `view`

your `result` is come from `context`.

Basically, django `view` render data to your own template. `context_processors` do that for you, and it's defined in `settings.py` (`TEMPLATES` - `OPTIONS`  - `context_processors`).

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            str(ROOT_DIR.path('templates')),
        ],
        # 'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                # you can add your own processors
                'your_app.path.to.custom_processors',
            ],
            'loaders': [
                'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here's more detail information about `context` ([official django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects))

It's why you can use `request`, `user` and other context data in your template.

If you want to use context in all templates, you can add your own `context_processors`. But in many times, you just want context only in particular template. (like your situation).

Then you can add your data to context, in your `views`.

If you're using Class Based View (I recommend using CBV), you can add by `get_context_data()`. like this.

```
class ProductView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'best.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['test'] = 'test context data'
        return context
```

You can add your own context data in existing `context`.

If you're using FBV, you can render template with your context. There're many ways to render (`render`, `render_to_response`, and so on.. You can check django docs for this. I guess you should use `render` cause `render_to_response` deprecated in `django 2.0`)

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    # View code here...
    context = {'test': 'test coooontext data' }
    return render(request, 'myapp/index.html', context)
```

By passing your own context data in views, you can use this in template.

So if you want to pass only 'name' and 'type', you can pass data just you want to use, not all. It's more effective working in view then template. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, but I have a hard time to learn where is the 'result' variable comes from? Do I need to make def variable in views.py first?

Comment: It depends on your `view`. I will update answer for `view`

Comment: thank you for your update! That way I know more on TEMPLATES in settings.py ()